# Source of randomness of GridsearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, gridsearchcv

I was using GridSearhCV to get the best parameter for the number of neurons in my neural network model.
I am trying to see why GridSearchCV produces different results (mean_test_score) each time even though I tried different methods to address this issue.

1. I think I am using CPU (Not GPU), judging from the result of timestamps.
2. I have set shuffle=False in KFold

```
cv=KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False)
```

3. The neural network model(KerasRegressor) I am using is in a separate cell which was already run before I run GridsearchCV, and when I just ran the GridSearchCV code block, still it gives different result each run (without rerunning the KerasRegressor code block). So any source of randomness in KerasRegressor should not affect the randomness after that (and also I am using tf.random.set_seed(seed) before defining the model)
4. I tried including the following code block to set the global seed

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

5. I included random_state as a key in param_grid dictionary but still I get different results.

```
param_grid = { 
'hidden_size1': [64],
'hidden_size2': [64],
'hidden_size3': [64],
'random_state': [2]
             }
```

The code I am using is

```
def make_model(optimizer="adam", hidden_size1=32, hidden_size2=32, hidden_size3=32, random_state=2):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(hidden_size1,  activation=activation,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],))) 
    model.add(Dense(hidden_size2,  activation=activation)) 
    model.add(Dense(hidden_size3,  activation=activation)) 
    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1],  activation='linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
tf.random.set_seed(seed)

clf = KerasRegressor(make_model,verbose=1)
param_grid = { 
'hidden_size1': [64],
'hidden_size2': [64],
'hidden_size3': [64],
'random_state': [2]
             }
```

and on the separate code block, I have

```
cv=KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False)
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv, return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and I am keep running this cell but everytime I get different result.

My question is if there is another source of randomness in GridSearchCV even when I disable the shuffle in KFold (Setting random state=integer is contradictory with Shuffle=False, so I just disabled Shuffle).

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the random seed does and how RNGs work, if you run the same cell multiple times, you will different results, since each time it is generating a new set of network weights, but the sequence is fixed already, you are just moving through the pseudorandom sequence of generated weights.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your comment! Then what should I do instead of using random seed to reproduce the result here?

Answer (score 0):

Like the commentor said, you are running GridSearch on a neural network with different weights every time, because they are randomly initiliazed. The solution to this would be to fill in initialization weights yourself.